# Restriction of $L^p$ functions to compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces

> Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded open and connected set in $\mathbb R^n$, $C\subseteq \Omega$ is a compact subset and $1<p<\infty$. Does the following equality hold: $$L^p(C) = \{f|_{C}:f\in L^p(\Omega)\}?$$

**My thoughts:** Since $$\int_C |f|_C|^p=\int_C|f|^p\leq \int_\Omega |f|^p,$$ so the reverse inclusion holds. However, I'm not sure how to prove/disprove about the forward inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \in L^{p}(C)$ define $g=f$ on $C$ and $0$ on $\Omega \setminus C$. Then $g \in L^{p}(\Omega)$ and $f=g|_C$.

Comment: Is it correct to write $L^p(C)$? Usually I have only seen $L^p$ spaces over open sets not over compact sets.

Comment: You only need a set,  a sigma algebra and  a measure to define $L^{p}$. The restriction of Lebesgue measure to any Borel set gives you an $L^{p}$ space. @Guest